# Conditional rasters value replacement in

Tags: google-earth-engine

In Google Earth Engine I would like to replace all the negative pixel values of each image of an ImageCollection with 0.

My approach is the following:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/MONTHLY_V1/VCMSLCFG').filterDate('2014-01-01', '2015-12-01').select('avg_rad');

var replacement = ee.Image(0);

var conditional = function(image) {
  image.where(image.lt(0), replacement);
};

var output = collection.map(conditional);
```

Howeve, I get the following error ressage

```
User-defined methods must return a value.
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, `User-defined methods must return a value.`

```js
var conditional = function(image) {
  return image.where(image.lt(0), replacement);
};
```

See it working: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d245677325a90780bda16f1f933fcccb

When you `map` a function over a collection, the returned value is the replacement for the current (iteration) value.

Comment: Thanks, this removes the error. Anyhow, I am not sure whether the approach works, because it runs *extremely* fast. Considering that the system should loop over all the pixels of 24 rasters, look for anything lower than 0 and replace it with 0, it seems a bit too fast. Do you think the code leads to the aimed objective?

Comment: Google Earth Engine IS fast. But anyhow, you can check it. I'll update my code so we can both check

Comment: If you want to understand a little more how it does it, read https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/deferred_execution. Basically, it does not loop over the whole collection when you run the code. It's called "lazy computation", which means that will only work if you need it (at request). For example, when adding the layer to the map, it actually executes the replacement for **that** image and then adds it to the map. But it is fast anyway =)